# rails root routes to a nested resourse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want that when I go to **"/"**, it redirect me to **"/dashboard/academies/index"**

```
namespace :dashboard do

    root to: "academies#index", as: :home

    resources :academies do
      resources :posts
      resources :enrollments
      resources :banners
    end

  end

  root to: "dashboard::academies#index" #<-----here
```

Comment: Probably `root to: "dashboard::academies#home"` could work?

Comment: Just run `rake routes`, you will get the syntax. Then use it. _Ask Rails to help you out_ Man!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  root to: "dashboard/academies#index"
```